# problem with bootstrap : id does not active whether it is displayed?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I am newbie with bootstrap and here is my problem. I code a very simple page with bootstrap 5 and link 4 button "Home" "Explore" "Create" "Share"

Here is my code

```
https://github.com/nguyencuc2586/project2
```

In my code, as you can see, I code for example

```
 <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#explore-head-section" class="nav-link">Explore</a>
 </li>
```

And below I coded

```
<section id="explore-head-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col text-center py-5">
                <div class="display-4">Explore</div>
                <p class="lead">Lorem, ipsum.</p>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Find out more</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

So I think when I clicked to the Explore, it must linked to the "Lorem, ipsum..." text ?

But it did not.

By the way, may be because the javascript below ?

Could you please give me some advices for this problem? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the jQuery full version, not slim version.

Please change the code for jQuery import

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

to as follows:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: If you are satisfied with my answer, can you accept it by checking?

Comment: I have been checked your code and you are right, thanks for your comment.

Comment: I mean, please add a green check to my answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to do this job just add listener and window scroll

```js
document.querySelector('.nav-link').addEventListener("click", function(e){
    var el = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("href");
    const y = el.top + window.scrollY;
    window.scroll({
        top: y,
        behavior: 'smooth'
    });
});
```

```html
<a href="#explore-head-section" class="nav-link">Explore</a>
 <div style="height: 1000px"></div>
 <section id="explore-head-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col text-center py-5">
                <div class="display-4">Explore</div>
                <p class="lead">Lorem, ipsum.</p>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Find out more</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
 <div style="height: 1000px"></div>
```